# Is there a possible way to put multiple icons in the right part of the item class using item-icon-right?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right" href="">
     <i class="icon icon-small ion-link"></i>
      {{song.name}} 

     <i   class="icon icon-small ion-plus-round" modal-select="" hide-   reset="true"  ng-model="selPlaylist"  options="selectableNames" modal-title="Choose playlist">
        <div class="option">
          <h2>{{option.name}}</h2>
        </div>
        </i >
      <i style="display:block;" class="icon ion-play button button-light" >
      </i>
    </div>
```

When i put the class "icon icon-small ion-plus-round" it goes to the left not to the right part of the list and also the icon overlaps with the icon at the left "icon icon-small ion-link".

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you should use `float: right` for `item-icon-right`

Comment: thanks for the reply @MortezaQorbanAlizade  i already solve it using item item-button-right .

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="list">
<div class="item item-button-right" href="">
 <i class="icon icon-small ion-link"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
  {{song.name}} 
<div class="buttons">
<i   class="icon icon-small ion-plus-round" modal-select="" hide-   reset="true"  ng-model="selPlaylist"  options="selectableNames" modal-title="Choose playlist">
<div class="option">
      <h2>{{option.name}}</h2>
    </div>
    </i >
  <i style="display:block;" class="icon ion-play button button-light" >
  </i>
</div>
</div>
```

here is the code